# SQLAlchemy `.fetchmany()` vs `.limit()`

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Assuming `query` is some already defined query. As far as I can tell, `connection.execute(query).fetchmany(n)` and `connection.execute(query).limit(n).fetchall()` apparently return the same result set. I'm wondering if one of them is more idiomatic or — more importantly — more performant?

Example usage would be:

```py
query = select([census.columns.state, (census.columns.pop2008 - census.columns.pop2000).label("pop_change")]).group_by(census.columns.state).order_by(desc("pop_change"))
results_1 = query.limit(5).fetchall()
results_2 = connection.execute(query).fetchmany(n)    #`results_2` = `results_1`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

limit will be a part of the sql query sent to the database server.

With fetchmany the query is executed without any limit, but the client (python code) requests only certain number of rows.

Therefore using limit should be faster in most cases.

Comment: Not only faster, but "safer" too. Depending on the DB-API layer, the unrestricted query could end up pulling all of the rows down to the client, with `.fetchmany` just pulling the subset of those rows into the `results_2` list.

Answer (score 4):

I have found `fetchmany` to be very useful when you need to get a very large dataset from the database but you do not want to load all of those results into memory. It allows you to process the results in smaller batches.

```python
result = conn.execution_options(stream_results=True).execute(
  SomeLargeTable.__table__.select()
)
while chunk:= result.fetchmany(10000) ## only get 10K rows at a time
  for row in chunk:
    ## process each row before moving onto the next chunk
```

Comment: this is a good use of the walrus operator!!